# Do Brooke and Franky have a dream?

Tags: one-piece

In One Piece, all of Luffy's crews have a dream to become something or discover something. Franky already accomplished his dream by building Sunny. Brooke's dream wasn't really that clear from the start either, if it was to become a well known musician, he's already accomplished by becoming soul king. So do these two have a/another dream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brooke wants to meet back up with Laboon, the whale at the start of the grand line.

From the wiki:

> Franky's dream is to create and travel with a dream ship which would
>   experience countless battles, can overcome extreme hardships and can
>   reach the end of the Grand Line. He has created the ship which the
>   Straw Hats are riding and it's his task to keep it in good condition.
>   Previously, one of his dreams was to beat Spandam to pieces,
>   fortunately this was fulfilled toward the end of the Enies Lobby Arc.

I do not agree with that based on the scene where they steal his speedo.  He wanted to build the boat; now he has.  Unlike the others, he isn't pursuing his dream but maintaining and improving what he already acheived.  Yet he still was willing to leave it unprotected (had no way to know about Kuma) for the better part of 2 years.

Comment: You seem to have it the wrong way around, Franky wasn't willing to set aside his dream randomly. He wanted to become powerful enough so that he could stand on his own to protect his ship and crew. This is eluded to multiple times before the Time Skip. Franky's dream of creating the ship that can travel the world will only be complete IFF Sunny travels the world. Thus he rides on it to see his dream to completion. This is similar to Zoro. In the beginning he told he'll kill Luffy if he stands in way of his dream. But he knocks Sanji out and nearly kills himself protecting Luffy from Kuma